# Why is music using a temperament other than 12-TET rare today?

Tags: scales, temperament

There are several other temperaments like 19-TET and 31-TET, but almost all modern music uses 12-TET. Why aren't the two former used more often?

Comment: 12-tone equal temperament isn't as common as you think.  It's fairly easy to find examples of major thirds tuned to a ratio of 5:4, which is basically 10/31 of an octave.  Of course these people aren't using 31-tone equal temperament either; they're just not using any equal temperament.

Comment: 12-TET is more common only in Western music, and only when "forced" to use fixed tuning. Even in Western classical music (but not only), musicians *fix* tuning of individual notes based on many aspects, and sometimes they also do it for fixed pitch instruments. Still, most of Western music is based on the "simpler" 12-TET, which may not be always "fully consonant", but is also easier and simpler to play and to listen to: our brains are quite adaptable, and tend to simplicity, unless educated to do otherwise. That's one reason for which pentatonic scales are more common in popular/folk music.

Comment: Instruments such as clarinets also use out-of-tune (read: not 12TET) notes as more convenient notes to use in trills (note that the alternate fingerings for the same note on a clarinet often produce notes several cents away from each other).

Comment: @Dekkadeci That has nothing to do with temperament. Those alternate and trill fingerings are usually only used when the notes are too fast for standard fingerings and fast enough that the bad intonation is not noticeable. There are only as few cases where an alternative might be used to for example bring a major third down to just intonation. Mostly the compensation is done by embouchure.

Comment: Non-autotuned vocalists, what temperament do they use? Neurotic, impulsive, phlegmatic?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Sopranos - sanguinic, altos - melancholic, tenors - choleric and basses - phlegmatic. (And now I'm not sure this is funny anymore.)

Comment: This question could be interpreted in two ways: 12 vs 19/31. Or 12-TET vs the zillions of others. (Even in the west Meantone, well-temperaments like Werckmeister etc ie not an ET were common till late 19th century)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What would the motivation be? Either you have an instrument with fixed pitches like a piano, and then it is not practical to play in anything other than 12-TET.  Or you don't, and then it is more compelling to play in locally converging pure intervals.

19-TET or 31-TET make mainly sense with synthesized music, and even then many synthesizers use the 12-TET based MIDI or a piano keyboard as their language of talking about pitch.

That makes for quite an entry threshold that will mainly be crossed by people obsessed with tunings, and that's at best a comparatively small fraction of composers, and not really a major interest for most of the audience.

The good enough is the enemy of the better, and 12-TET is good enough for most.  And those not satisfied with it will more often than not rather lean towards well-tempered tunings than equally tempered ones.

Comment: It's *possible* to tune a fixed-pitch instrument to something other than 12-TET, but you need a keyboard layout that supports, e.g., C# and D♭ having separate keys.

Comment: I think the reason why so many people are like "what's the point?" when asked about alternative tunings is because they haven't actually heard what music, or even basic chords and scales, sound like. The more people are shown the possibilities beyond 12-TET, the more accepting they will be of them. I should also mention that there are isomorphic keyboards that support a whole bunch of different tunings despite being fixed-pitch instruments, although a lot of them right now are only controllers as opposed to something that has everything built in.

Comment: @ElEctric I agree, but it's important not to expect people to just fall in love with 31-edo on first contact. Although many will appreciate that a major chord sounds somewhat more pure in it than in 12-edo, this does come at a cost of more complexity (even when using something like the Lumatone), and while this is itself also an opportunity it's not a tradeoff everybody is willing to make.

Comment: @ElEctric I’ve heard a lot of non-12TET music, and currently I’m borrowing a Bohlen-Pierce clarinet, and I still don’t see (or hear) the point. 31 EDO and others just sound weird. And it’s a big pain and kinda expensive to make using any other system practical. So it seems like going through a lot of trouble for no benefit to me.

Comment: @leftaroundabout To my ears the improvement of the sonority of a major chord played in 31 EDO on a lumatone is very subtle, while the difference between a melody I like in 12 TET versus a melody I don’t like is huge. So it makes a lot more sense to me to spend the most time and effort making better music in 12 TET over spending a lot of time and effort figuring out how to effectively use a microtonal instrument and/or work with or create a microtonal ensemble for a difference that is barely audible even to my well-trained ears.

Comment: @ToddWilcox If you prefer to continue on in 12-TET, that's perfectly okay. But if music students are exposed to alternative tunings from early on, they will be more likely to accept and use them, even if most still stick to 12-TET. Many people will find the differences worthwhile, as subtle as they may be, but with the way things are now even most of the best musicians don't get this opportunity because they aren't shown other options, and by the time they finally do hear other tunings they're no longer able to appreciate what they have to offer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I get what you're saying about BP and 31-edo, it kind of matches my own experiences. However, to my ears the subtle difference between a good string quartet or Barbershop quartet doing just intonation andthe 12-edo approximation to the same music makes for a _huge_ improvement in hearing enjoyment, so I definitely don't agree with the conclusion that it's not worth it to go beyond 12-edo. And I definitely wouldn't say 31-edo sounds weird, lots of diatonic music sounds very similar in 12-edo or 31-edo.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In fact, I can already think of many non-classical songs that I think would sound much better in 31-TET than in 12-TET.

Comment: @ElEctric The music students I know are so busy developing their aural skills in 12 TET and playing in ensembles and learning their 12 TET based instruments they just don’t have the time to learn anything else and don’t have the money to own other instruments. I guess the strings and trombone players don’t have the instrument expense concerns but what’s everyone else to do?

Comment: @ToddWilcox most music students don't even learn 12-edo anyway, at least not at first. They start out diatonically, in a key that fits their instrument well, and then expand from there. At some point you get to the "and here we have the note D♯, which is actually the same as E♭ which we used in another piece!" revelation. That wouldn't happen in 31-edo, but everything before this would be much the same.

Comment: @ToddWilcox "The music students I know are so busy developing their aural skills in 12 TET and playing in ensembles and learning their 12 TET based instruments they just don’t have the time to learn anything else" That's because the music programme that the students you know are going through fails to mention other tunings. As I mentioned earlier, the more music students are shown alternate tunings, the more likely it is that they will find them useful, and what you said is actually a problem with music education. If you want more insight, see my updated reply to OP.

Comment: I think this whole Q&A shows that some people are all about other tuning systems and other people don’t see enough benefit in them. Sticking with 12TET will not limit my career paths in any significant way and in order to do very much outside of 12TET would cost me money and time. Fir me the costs far outweigh the benefits and I suspect many others feel the same way.

Comment: @Toddwilcox It's clear at this point that you're doing everything possible to dodge anything that goes against your views while at the same time pushing your views across as if they're the only ones that are correct. Seriously? Why do you do this?

Comment: @ElEctric the only thing I really object to is the notion that the only reason why more people don’t like 22 EDO or 31 EDO or 19 EDO or B-P is that they haven’t heard enough of it. Firstly, I’ve heard a lot of it and hear nothing clearly better about any of them. Second, if I don’t hear it with my trained ears, I’m skeptical that the music listening public is likely to have any preference for it. Finally, the fact that it isn’t more popular seems to support the idea that most people don’t prefer it. If it were clearly better it would grow in popularity because of that.

Comment: @ToddWilcox What I'm suggesting is that the reason it isn't more popular is because people don't even know about them. You obviously can't force it onto people, but if they aren't even shown the possibilities early on in their musical training, they won't get to make an informed decision. The reason why you don't seem to hear it or see the point is because you've spent so much of your life tuning your ears to 12-TET that you're long past the point of no return.

Comment: @ToddWilcox As for what tunings to show people, I would show people 19 and 31, but not 22, Bohlen–Pierce, or anything esoteric. But again, the problem is not the alleged "pointlessness" of other tunings, it's the fact that music programmes don't even tell people about other options, thereby preventing people from being able to decide for themselves.

Comment: @ElEctric I’m not convinced you’re correct about that. You might be, you might not. Perhaps the causality is reversed. Perhaps music programs don’t go into other tunings because too few people find them valuable. Beyond that I don’t think music programs in universities are that crucial in terms of what music is being made. A lot of music is made by people without music degrees and a lot of people go way beyond the knowledge from a music degree when making music. If 31-TET music would be more successful commercially than 12-TET, I’m pretty sure someone would have figured that out long ago.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I've discussed this with a number of others and I think that the drilling of 12-TET into people's minds as the only right way to do things is a symptom of a much bigger problem with education. Specifically, I would attribute it to outdated teaching methods that don't allow sufficient room for teachers to be more innovative, while telling teachers to "just do it" without giving them sufficient guidance on *how* things should be done.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Because, again, they've only been exposed to 12-TET all their lives and are past the point of no return. *Never assume pointlessness or needless complexity when ignorance, laziness, or complacency will suffoce.*

Comment: @ElEctric I think you’ve made your views clear.

Answer (score 6):

Using an equal temperament makes it practical to transpose music into arbitrary keys without affecting which intervals are consonant and dissonant.  When using non-equal termperaments, transposing most pieces of music into at least some keys would result in consonant intervals becoming dissonant, dissonant intervals becoming consonant, or both.

An advantage of 12-TET is that it includes pitches that have perfect 2:1, 4:1, and 8:1 ratios, and almost perfect 3:1 ratios and 6:1 ratios, without needing an excessive number of pitches.  The only ratios below 8:1 that are not accurately represented are 5:1 and 7:1.  While a 29-tone or 41-tone equal temperament could offer even more accurate 3:1 and 6:1 ratios, subdividing each octave into 29 or 41 pitches would be much more awkward than subdividing into 12.

Comment: In 29-TET and 41-TET, the major thirds are approximately an 81/64 in ratio while minor thirds are 32/27, making both somewhat dissonant and tense-sounding. 19, 31, and even 43 and 50 are a lot less awkward in comparison since their major and minor thirds are much closer to their just ratios.

Comment: @ElEctric: Some temperaments come closer than 12-TET to having a 5:1 ratio available but sacrifice the accuracy of the best available 3:1.  Given that the *function* of the perfect fifth in a chord is usually to sonically blend with the root, while the function of the third is usually to add "color", pushing the perfect fifth from being 0.113% flat to being 0.416% flat would work against that function.  Consider an E chord, with a root at 164.81Hz and a fifth at 987.77.  A 6x harmonic would be 988.86Hz, yielding a beat of about 1Hz--only noticeable on long notes.

Comment: @ElEctric: I've heard music samples at 19-TET, and to my ear they don't really work, and I think the perfect fifth is the problem.  The 12-TET perfect fifth beat frequencies are slow relative to the tempo of most music, and fits with the way that most instruments' sound undulates with time.  The 19-TET beat frequencies are much faster.

Comment: Yeah, 19-TET can sound very strange to a lot of people since its intervals are wildly different from what we are used to. I personally think 31-TET would be the optimal alternative tuning for much non-classical music, since the differences between its sound and 12-TET's sound are enough to be noticeable but they aren't so much that it sounds jarring, unlike 19-TET, and the number of notes is still manageable on instruments like guitars.

Comment: @ElEctric: The only way I could see 31-TET as being manageable would be if there were a way of easily notating what pitches the staff positions would represent, and how far a note should be displaced from its "staff-position" note.  Trying to almost triple the number of frets on a guitar doesn't seem practical to me, though.

Comment: 31-TET can be notated with standard Western notation. In this case, a sharp raises by 2 steps, so C to C♯ is 2 steps, C to D♭ is 3 steps, and C to D is 5. The notes from E to F are E, F♭, E♯, and F. As for guitars, maybe more people will start going fretless if they don't want to deal with the extra frets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150303/discussion-between-el-ectric-and-supercat).

Answer (score 5):

- The harmonic and melodic language is more familiar, and change is difficult to introduce.
- Instruments are generally designed for 12-TET.
- There is an enormous body of music that uses microtonality — almost all non-Western music does — but it remains less known in the west, and it doesn't use systems like 19- or 31-TET.
- For Western music, not much is actually gained by using other temperaments. The music that does use it tends to focus on musical elements other than melody and harmony: timbre, rhythm, individual intervallic sounds.
- Popular music, in particular, relies on a common musical language to appeal to the largest possible audience. For rock'n'roll and its descendants, that's 12-TET. It's conceivable this could change eventually with the rise of electronic music, but it will be a long time coming.

Comment: "Instruments are generally designed for 12-TET." This is very much a chicken-and-egg situation, where instruments are generally designed for 12-TET since 12-TET is so popular but 12-TET is so popular since instruments are generally designed for it. I think, in the future, once alternative tunings become more widely known in Western music then we'll see an increasing amount of (some) non-12-TET versions of instruments, like guitars, that used to be mostly 12-TET.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you listen to. In recent years I discovered how fun it is to play fretless instruments and then I actively searched out music in other temperaments. I am doubtful I would have even heard about them if I hadn't begun playing these instruments myself. So I wouldn't be surprised if it is simply because people do not know about it.

Comment: It's very likely that people not knowing about other tunings **is** the real reason, and this is in turn a result of music education failing to mention them. I'm quite appalled that you and I are almost the only people here who even thought that this was a possibility.

Answer (score -4):

We have a 12-tone system because no one can find a better number.

If we lost all music, it would return in the same form with the same musical key structure.

In the same way, if we lost standard tuning on guitar, it would come back again because no one can find a better tuning.

There won't be any new tunings on guitar that are more successful.

Comment: What is meant by "better"?

Comment: This is insulting to most of the world's music, which does not use the 12-TET system, was formed before it, and has lasted for millennia.

Comment: I would actually concede that there is _a good chance_ that 12-edo would be re-developed anew if all music was lost. But it's also perfectly plausible that for example ¼-comma meantone would hold on for longer and then be gradually replaced by 31-edo (which is better compatible with ¼-comma than 12-edo). - As for guitar tuning, I completely disagree: if standard tuning were forgotten (and all songs written in it) and guitarists had to come up with something from scratch, it would almost certainly be at least slightly different.